# Accessing the WebKit API from Haskell via something other than WebKitGTK

Tags: haskell, webkit, ghc, webkitgtk, ghcjs

I'm trying to understand if there is any other way to access the WebKit API directly from from a Haskell (`ghc-7.10.2` currently) program without having to go through something like [`webkitgtk3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/webkitgtk3), which is a Haskell wrapper around [WebKitGTK](http://webkitgtk.org).

It appears WebKitGTK does not expose the full WebKit API, for example these are offered by WebKit:

- [`HTMLCanvasElement` @ developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/WebKit/Reference/HTMLCanvasElementRef/)
- [`CanvasRenderingContext2DClass` @ developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/WebKit/Reference/CanvasRenderingContext2DClassRef/)

but not by WebKitGTK:

- [`WebKitDOMHTMLCanvasElement` @ webkitgtk.org](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitdomgtk/stable/WebKitDOMHTMLCanvasElement.html)

Is there any way to access the WebKit API of a running WebKit.app or Safari.app especially on OS X but also Linux and Windows?

*P.S. Some background to this: I'm developing an application using GHCJS, but since GHCJS is so much slower (and doesn't integrate with all Emacs IDE features, I think), I also want to be able to compile the same (or almost the same) code base using GHC. So I got familiar with `webkitgtk` and even spent several days trying to [get `webkitgtk-2.4.9` to build on OS X via Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/pull/1077), because `webkitgtk3` only currently builds against `2.4.9`, only to find out that the nice and fully featured Canvas API which WebKit exposes is [not at all available through WebKitGTK](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152250). Hence the search for alternatives. And it is also for this reason I'm adding [ghcjs](/questions/tagged/ghcjs) — it is very likely that other users of GHCJS will find this post interesting.*